# how to plot the particular data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot a graph

```
sex ch r  p
'm' 10 18 17
'm'  9  6 6
```

I tried joint plot and barplot and I don't know how to plot

```
sns.jointplot(x=df.index,y=np.sum(df))
```

So I used my code on x-axis data frame and y-axis sum of columns data frame and get error:

> operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (36,)

I want to plot a graph where on x-axis all the columns for the plot and
y-axis the sum of columns means ch y-axis is 19 and r taxis is 24 and p taxis is 23

I tried using join plot but the syntax seems wrong

```
jointplot(x=df.index,y=np.sum(df))
```

I expect the output to be
on `x-axis` there should be columns ch,r,p
and on `y-axis` there should be total of columns I got an empty graph showing an error:

> Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Answer (score 0):

I think you need aggregate `sum` and reshape by `unstack`, so possible use [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html):

```
df = df.groupby('sex').sum().unstack().reset_index()
df.columns = ['cat','sex','val']
print (df)
  cat sex  val
0  ch   m   19
1   r   m   24
2   p   m   23

sns.catplot(x='sex', y='val', hue='cat', data=df, kind='bar')
```

Another solution by [`plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df.groupby('sex').sum().plot.bar()
```